# ELF patching, binding issue

Tags: linux, gcc, binding, g++, elf

Currently I am trying to patch an ELF executable object file.

I am testing my utility, using the primitive hello-world application. Everything seems to remain fine after patching, but when it comes to execution, the application segfaults.

When patching, I also insert a new shared object dependency. To understand what goes wrong, in parallel I managed to link the shared object into my test application. So that I receive the well-formed `g++`-made result, which I can compare to my algorithm result (more or less).

The issue I ran into is that during execution my modified hello-world app cannot call `std::cout` routine, because the `std::ostream::sentry::sentry(std::ostream&)` ctor fails; I managed to dive into the problem, using the `gdb`. When debugging and comparing to the well-formed result, I managed to figure out what is wrong. It appears that the the symbol `std::cout` / `_ZSt4cout` relocation binding is sort of misused. Despite both results have exactly the same `DT_NEEDED` entries in the `.dynamic` section (in the same order as well), and despite they both have an import symbol entry for `std::cout` in the `.dynsym` section, with accordingly modified `.gnu.version` and `.gnu.hash` contents, - despite all these, - the `std::ios_base::Init::Init()` function, when resolving the `std::cout` object, operates differently for the both results. For the well-formed result - over the proper entry in the `.bss` section of the hello-world application, while for the my algo result - over the `std::cout` entry (as the `readelf` util verifies) in the `.got` section of the `libstdc++` shared library.

Last, but not least, when executing with the `LD_DEBUG=bindings` option, I receive the following output for the well-formed result (added `std::cin` / `_ZSt3cin` for contrast):

```
...
     10067: binding file /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 [0] to ./hello_world_wellformed [0]: normal symbol `_ZSt4cout' [GLIBCXX_3.4]
     10067: binding file /home/user/Documents/Test/libmyexternal.so [0] to ./hello_world_wellformed [0]: normal symbol `_ZSt4cout' [GLIBCXX_3.4]
     10067: binding file ./hello_world_wellformed [0] to /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 [0]: normal symbol `_ZSt4cout' [GLIBCXX_3.4]
...
     10067: binding file /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 [0] to ./hello_world_wellformed [0]: normal symbol `_ZSt3cin' [GLIBCXX_3.4]
     10067: binding file ./hello_world_wellformed [0] to /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 [0]: normal symbol `_ZSt3cin' [GLIBCXX_3.4]
...
```

While for the algo-modified result:

```
...
     10027: binding file /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 [0] to /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 [0]: normal symbol `_ZSt4cout' [GLIBCXX_3.4]
     10027: binding file /home/user/Documents/Test/libmyexternal.so [0] to /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 [0]: normal symbol `_ZSt4cout' [GLIBCXX_3.4]
     10027: binding file ./hello_world_algotest  [0] to /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 [0]: normal symbol `_ZSt4cout' [GLIBCXX_3.4]
...
     10027: binding file /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 [0] to /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 [0]: normal symbol `_ZSt3cin' [GLIBCXX_3.4]
     10027: binding file ./hello_world_algotest [0] to /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 [0]: normal symbol `_ZSt3cin' [GLIBCXX_3.4]
...
```

How can I fix the issue or what might be the reason for such behavior? How do `glibc` and `libstdc++` deal with such situations and how come the algo-modified app's `std::cout` entry became 'invisible' for the libraries (despite the `readelf`, `objdump`, and `nm` utils show that everything is correct)?

Naturally, both `glibc` and `libstdc++` versions and the same, both hello-world apps compiled under the same `g++` version. `.bss` section resides properly, all sections and segments have proper flags set.

Answer (score 0):

Digging inside the `glibc` source, using the `gdb` (and lost a couple days), I reached the `_dl_lookup_symbol_x` and `do_lookup_x` functions, defined in `dl-lookup.c`; arguments passed showed me the difference (between the well-formed and algo-derived results) was in hashes. Well, I forgot that the GNU hash table has been modified incorrectly. Once you add an import function, you have to change the GNU hash table indexes (luckily, you do not have to rebuild the whole hash table, just update indexes; do not forget that, when adding an import function, you still have to change the .dynsym and GNU version table contents) (one really cool explanation of the whole GNU hashing concept can be seen here: https://flapenguin.me/elf-dt-gnu-hash). By the way, I found and fixed a bug with the obsolete .bss section number (happened because of sections rebuilding).